# "Deferred Callback" in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, deferred-execution

I believe what I'm trying to do is referred to as a "deferred callback" at least in some paradigms.

Basically I need a way to call a method after another method returns. Something like this:

```
- (void)someMethod:data
{
    [someObject doSomethingAfterCurrentMethodReturns]
}
```

I would like to be able to do this because a library for an external accessory that I have to use will crash the app if I do the thing I want to do within the method. This is noted in the documentation for the library. My current workaround involves an additional user interaction -- throw up UIAlertView and put the method behind a button click.

I've seen some libraries that seem to handle this. Is there a built in way to handle this in Objective C?

Comment: The method you are calling is asynchronous?

Comment: It's not, so "deferred callback" is probably not the perfect label. Hence the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the number of parameters the method has you could use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. Or you could start an `NSTimer` and call the method when it fires.

Comment: My fault: my method doesn't take an argument. And this doesn't work: `[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:Nil afterDelay:50]`

Comment: And never mind, I was assuming NSTimeinterval would be in milliseconds!

Comment: Does it have to be specific delay time can it be with a condition to end of a loop or such

Comment: If you have a specific condition why are you looking for a deferred call?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but wanted to provide an option that I like better than provided solution because I don't know if it is guaranteed to work and I didn't want to test it.

You are correct that you want defer equivalent. I too was looking for this. Other implementations suggest a custom class that leverage auto-release.

I liked this solution best as it is simple and inline:

```
- (void)foo {
// code to execute in foo
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    // code to execute after foo() returns
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
__attribute__((cleanup(...)))
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as answer. Please explain your answer/implementation.

Comment: There's more info about this here: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2017/even-swiftier-objective-c/

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a `defer` statement in ObjC similar to Go's `defer`. See my [blog post](http://a-coding.com/defer-in-objective-c/) and the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/aleph7/AIDefer). It would look like this:

```
- (void)someMethod:(id)data
{
  defer(^(){
    [someObject doSomethingAfterCurrentMethodReturns];
  });
  ///...
}
```